# which is faster mysqli_prepare or mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, prepare

which is faster to :

1.

```
$name  = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$age   = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['age']);
$email = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$query = "INSERT INTO `tablename` VALUES ('$name','$age','$email');";

$sql->query($query) or die($query.'<br />'.$sql->error);
```

2.

```
 $name  = $_POST['name'];
    $age   = $_POST['age'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $query = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO `tablename` VALUES ('?','?','?');");

    $query->bind_param("sis",$name,$age,$email);
    $query->execute();
```

when using prepare and bind param you are sending more request to mysql database which will take more time , because there are more requests, and each request has it's connection time .

that's true if mysql database are not located in the localhost server.

is this statement correct ?
thanks

Comment: Not completely correct, no.... the MySQLi interface is smart enough to only send bind param values to the database server once, on the exeute as far as I'm aware.... and a nanosecond difference in performance (even to a remote database server) should not be considered more important than properly securing your code..... especially as you can use the same prepared statement repeatedly with different bind values, which makes it faster in that circumstance

Comment: And you should already have connected to the database, so there should be no connection time involved in `prepare()`/`bind()`/`execute()` (or indeed in `query()`)

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you for your respone, yes that's right there will not be more connection. but prepare statement will send requst to the database and i'm referring to this request time.

Comment: @MarkBaker generally i don't query the same query , so binding values to the same prepared statement is rare case.

Comment: You'll also find differences between prepared statements with PDO and with MySQLi.... PSO supports client-side prepared statements, where all the binding work is handled in the PHP interface , and only a single request is sent to the database with both the prepared statement and the bind vars in one go

Comment: In general, MySQLi performs insignificantly faster than PDO in benchmarks - ~2.5% for non-prepared statements, and ~6.5% for prepared ones

Comment: But your basic mysqli query has three `escape` statements, which are overhead there, and that pretty much negate any speed benefits from the binds

Comment: @MarkBaker yes that's right . does 'mysql escape string' send request to mysql database ?

Comment: No it doesn't but it's still code overhead in the original..... you're basically sending one communication with the db server if you use straight MySQLi query(), one communication with the db server if you use PDO prepared statements, and three communications with the db server if you're using MySQLi prepared statements (albeit the first two of those are minimal overhead, not all communications with the db server are equal overhead).... which is one reason why PDO is preferred over MySQLi

Comment: with pdo there are also three communication : 1. for prepare statement. 2.for bind data. 3. for executing query . righ ?

Comment: I believe that PDO handles all the initial work client side, and only sends all the components to the db server in a single request on the execute

Answer (score 1):

The actual purpose to use a prepared statement in sql is to cut the cost of processing queries; NOT to separate data from query. That's how it's being used w/ php NOW, not how it was designed to be used in the first place. With SQL you cut the cost of executing multiple similar queries down by using a prepared statement.. Doing so cuts out the parsing, validation and most often generates an execution plan for said query up front. Which is why they run faster in a loop, than their  IMMEDIATE Query cousins do. Do not assume that just because someone uses php and this function this way does not mean that it is THE way, or only way to do it. Although it is more secure than general queries but they are also more limited in what they can do or more precisely how you can go about doing it.

I think below ref link will be useful to you:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the case that you mentioned is rare, generally if i execute one query. i will not execute it again .